# Edit user profiles form without using django admin

Tags: python-3.x, django-1.6

I am developing a simple LMS system where I have 3 stakeholders Administrator, Faculty Members and Students. Administrator can create, edit, delete, block and list user accounts, with my developement so far I am able to create and list all users.

Now I am stuck at editing user profile, my requirement is when I click on any listed users it should open my extended/customized user profile in a form and I should have the ability to edit any opened user profile.

Below are my code snippets:

MODELS.PY:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
class UserInformation(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    degree = models.ForeignKey(Degree, null=True, blank=True)
    stakeholder = models.ForeignKey(Stakeholder)
    cell_number = models.CharField(max_length=32, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

VIEWS.PY (to create user):

```
def ad_create_user(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        firstname = request.POST['firstname']
        lastname = request.POST['lastname']
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        email = request.POST['email']
        group = request.POST['group']
        degree = request.POST['degree']
        cell_no = request.POST['cell_no']
        new_user = User.objects.create_user(username, email, password)
        new_user.first_name = firstname
        new_user.last_name = lastname
        new_user.save()

        if group == 'option_one':
            set_group = 3
            new_user.groups.add(3)
            userinfo = UserInformation(user=User.objects.get(username=username), degree=Degree.objects.get(pk=degree),
                                       stakeholder=Stakeholder.objects.get(pk=set_group), cell_number=cell_no)
            userinfo.save()
        if group == 'option_two':
            set_group = 2
            new_user.groups.add(2)
            userinfo = UserInformation(user=User.objects.get(username=username),
                                       stakeholder=Stakeholder.objects.get(pk=set_group), cell_number=cell_no)
            userinfo.save()
        if group == 'option_three':
            set_group = 1
            new_user.groups.add(1)
            userinfo = UserInformation(user=User.objects.get(username=username),
                                       stakeholder=Stakeholder.objects.get(pk=set_group), cell_number=cell_no)
            userinfo.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/administrator/user_management/')
    return render(request, 'MobiApp/create_user.html', {'form': CreateUserForm()})
```

FORMS.PY (to create user):

```
class CreateUserForm(forms.Form):
    firstname = forms.CharField(max_length=64)
    lastname = forms.CharField(max_length=64)
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=16)
    password = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(),
    )
    email = forms.EmailField()
    group = forms.ChoiceField(
        choices=(
            ('option_one', "Student"),
            ('option_two', "Faculty Member"),
            ('option_three', "Administrator"),
        ),
        widget = forms.RadioSelect,
        initial = 'option_one',
    )
    degree = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Degree.objects.all())
    cell_no = forms.CharField()

    helper = FormHelper()
    helper.form_class = 'form-horizontal'
    helper.layout = Layout(
        Field('firstname', css_class='input-xlarge'),
        Field('lastname', css_class='input-xlarge'),
        Field('username', css_class='input-xlarge'),
        Field('password', css_class='input-xlarge'),
        Field('email', css_class='input-xlarge'),
        'group',
        'degree',
        Field('cell_no', css_class='input-xlarge'),
        FormActions(
            Submit('create', 'Create!', css_class="btn-primary"),
        )
    )
```

I found many questions similar to this but none of them helped me and my requirement is also little different as user is not editing his/her profile but administrator is editing profile of any user.

Just for your information:

- I am using Django-Crispy-Forms
- When I click on any user of edit profile, its URL will be something like this http://myapp.com/administrator/edit_user/11

where 11 is the user id

Thanks in advance, let me know if you need any further information.

Comment: No one there to help me :(

Comment: In Django-1.6 you can extend User Model by using [AUTH_USER_MODEL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/settings/#auth-user-model).

Comment: Thanks Charlesliam, I am able to extend my user model, but my actual issue is to edit user profiles from administrator (not Django admin) as stated above.

Comment: This is what something I need [UserChangeForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.forms.UserChangeForm). Can someone help me in using this in my views ?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you looking for - [Generic views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### EDIT:

Here's my final proposed solution (`charlesliam` also made a reference to this in his comment)

We will subclass `AbstractUser` to add extra fields to the user. Obviously, there's other ways of doing this, but using `AbstractUser` should suffice your requirements. You'd have to syncdb for model changes to propagate.

#### SETTINGS.PY

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL  = 'app.UserInformation' # Points to our custom User model which we will define in models.py
```

#### MODELS.PY

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class UserInformation(AbstractUser):
    # user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True) <---- Remove this field
    degree = models.ForeignKey(Degree, null=True, blank=True)
    stakeholder = models.ForeignKey(Stakeholder)
    cell_number = models.CharField(max_length=32, null=True, blank=True)
```

#### FORMS.PY

```
class EditUserForm(forms.ModelForm): #fixed typo. It's forms.ModelForm, not models.ModelForm
    class Meta:
        model = UserInformation
```

#### VIEWS.PY

```
from forms.py import EditUserForm

def edit_user (request, id):
    user = User.objects.get(id=11)
    if request.method == 'POST': #If form has been submitted
        form = EditUserForm(request.POST, instance=user)
        if form.is_valid(): #All good. Validation passed
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/your-view/') # Redirect after POST
    else:
            form = EditUserForm(instance=user) # Unbound form

    return render(request, 'MobiApp/edit_user.html', {'form': form})
```

#### edit_user.html

```
{% load crispy_forms_tags %} 

{% crispy form %}
```

will give you a pre-populated form with the user instance, which you can edit and POST back.

Now with regards to user authentication, you can check if the currently logged in user is superuser (administrator), and proceed with the form editing logic.

So in your **VIEWS.PY**:

```
def edit_user (request, id):
    current_user = request.user
    if current_user.is_superuser:
        ...
```

Alternatively, you can assign the currently logged-in user to any group and then check if the user is member of that group, then proceed with form editing.

I hope that helps.

#### REFERENCES:

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/forms/modelforms/
- https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/models.py#L353
- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/
- [When to use the Custom User Model in Django 1.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15123596/when-to-use-the-custom-user-model-in-django-1-5)

Comment: Thanks Farhan for you detailed reply.

I am facing 2 issues,

First, I am just seeing fields of UserInformation model (user, stakeholder, degree and cell_number) and not Django Auth model fields (like username, firstname, lastname, email and Group)

Second, even the fields from UserInformation are not pre-populated.